# from when do we have the field of computer vision?

Tags: reference-request, history, computer-vision

when was the field of computer vision created and what are the disciplines that gave birth to it? I would appreciate it if you could give some web references that have the answer.

Comment: What research have you done? What have you found?

Answer (score 2):

Here are pointers to popular initiatives and breakthroughs in Computer Vision.

This paper starts the history of computer vision with Larry Roberts' thesis (around 1960):

http://cds.cern.ch/record/400313/files/p21.pdf

David Marr is also a huge name in the field and is mentioned in the paper.

The related field of computer geometry is rooted in such names as M. Minsky (Perceptrons, 1969 - although about neural networks explicitly, the book is highly related to the initial steps of computer vision and geometry). Bentley and his quadtree data structure is pervasively used in computer vision:

http:/www-ma2.upc.es/~geoc/mat2q1011/presentacioGeoC-2.ppt

I guess that the moment digital imaging started existing, researchers have started thinking about those topics. Most of the works quoted here date back to the 60's and 70's, which makes sense. Back then, you had the Voyager project at NASA.

Legacy machinery that do things similar to what robotics accomplishes with computer vision today can be found here:

http://cyberneticzoo.com/cyberneticanimals/1962-5-hopkins-beast-autonomous-robot-mod-ii-sonarvision-jhu-apl-american/

In the proto-computer vision era, you could then have the school of cybernetics founded by McCullogh. The school was started slightly after WW2 from work done during the war.